# How can I use a where clause to select?

Tags: c#, linq

`Client` table has columns `Id, Name, Value`.

I'm trying to use a `.where` clause to return the records where `name` column has a value of `CLIENTACCESS`

```
ClientAccountAccess clientAccessCodes = db.ClientAccountAccesses
                    .Where(x => x.name == "CLIENTACCESS").Select();

return clientAccessCodes.value;
```

I don't think I'm too far off....any help?

Comment: What's actually wrong with what you have? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), if there is no record that mathces your condition then it will return null.

```
ClientAccountAccess clientAccessCodes = db.ClientAccountAccesses
                                      .Where(x => x.name == "CLIENTACCESS")
                                      .FirstOrDefault();
if(clientAccessCodes != null)
    return clientAccessCodes.value;
else
   return null;
```

Also you can use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overloaded version of `FirstOrDefault` and you can shorten that statement like this:

```
var clientAccessCodes = db.ClientAccountAccesses
                          .FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == "CLIENTACCESS");
```

Comment: Or, better yet, you can just use FirstOrDefault instead of the Where: FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == "CLIENTACCESS")

Comment: You also don't need the `else`.

Comment: In fact, you don't need the entire `if` statement. Just return db... Null will be returned because of the `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: @BobHorn if you look carefully, he doesn't return ClientAccountAccess object, he returns it's value.So, it can't be done with one line unless if you  execute  same query twice. `return db.ClientAccountAccesses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == "CLIENTACCESS") == null ? db.ClientAccountAccesses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == "CLIENTACCESS").value : null`

Comment: I was guessing that he was mistakenly using `Value`. But we would need to see his method signature to know what he's supposed to return. He hasn't said yet what is actually wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `Select()`. Just do this:

```
return db.ClientAccountAccesses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == "CLIENTACCESS");
```

Comment: Nope, it will return `IEnumerable<ClientAccountAccess>` not a single value.

Comment: Ha. Oops. Fixed. Thanks.